# dockerfile Add file can not be found

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Server Version: 18.03.1-ce ,RHEL 7.2 .Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ENV http_proxy http://192.168.156.25:3128
ENV https_proxy http://192.168.156.25:3128
RUN  apk update && apk upgrade && apk add netcat-openbsd
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/licensingservice
ADD @project.build.finalName@.jar /usr/local/licensingservice/
ADD run.sh run.sh
RUN chmod +x run.sh
CMD ./run.sh
```

it build without error:

```
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8fa60876c229
Step 5/9 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/licensingservice

 ---> Using cache
 ---> bca46b1256e1
Step 6/9 : ADD licensing-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/licensingservice/

 ---> a66979ed3755
Step 7/9 : ADD run.sh ./run.sh

 ---> 95b492565374
Step 8/9 : RUN chmod +x run.sh

 ---> Running in eec3075c30f3
Removing intermediate container eec3075c30f3
 ---> 96a2d7b89b80
Step 9/9 : CMD ./run.sh

 ---> Running in c338e9d33371
Removing intermediate container c338e9d33371
 ---> 324d5a83cf84
ProgressMessage{id=null, status=null, stream=null, error=null, progress=null, progressDetail=null}
Successfully built 324d5a83cf84
Successfully tagged johncarnell/tmx-licensing-service:chapter4
```

but docker run -it 324d5a83cf84:

```
/bin/sh: ./run.sh: not found
```

I debug using `docker run --rm -it 324d5a83cf84 cat ./run.sh`,it print the file well. 
run.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello1"
```

Comment: what is the content of `run.sh` ?

Comment: just some echo,java command

Comment: I ask because I copy-pasted your dockerfile and it works fine. My `run.sh` is just `echo it works !`. So I suspect there is an error in your `run.sh`. Try: `docker run -it --rm 324d5a83cf84  ./run.sh`. Does it work ?

Comment: @Derlin ,no ,it still can not be found even replace the run.sh with simple echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are working on Windows and you are using the default Windows newline: `CR LF`. Change to `LF` in your `run.sh` and it will work like a charm.

But how to do that you ask? Open `run.sh` in Notepad++ and look at the bottom right of the window. Click on *Windows (CR LF)* and select *Unix (LF)*.

Comment: thank you very much, I have confirm this by replacing run.sh with the file clone from github directly